Cypress client certificate toggle
I want to use client certificates for login instead of classic login in my project. we have different user levels like admin and normal user. when I use the config file I only can login with one role . is there any way that I login with one user and in other test login again with other user ?
how can I pass different client certificates to different test functions ?
toggle client certificate user in cypress

Does this answer your question? How can i use multiple(not single) client certificates to login in with cypress?

No it is not working.Cypress.config('clientCertificates', [ configCert ]) is not working because they made it read only
